# Value binding with html elements in lightning framework

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In below code I am trying to bind input value with one of the sobject property but currently it is not getting binded. What I need to do so that sobject property will be binded with the html input element. I know I can use ui components but with that LDS is not working as expected so I choose to go with input where styles are working very fine but

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.question.Type__c == 'Radio'}">        
        <fieldset class="slds-form-element">
            <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">{!v.question.Description__c}</legend>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
              <aura:iteration items="{!v.question.Answers__r}" var="answer" >  
              <label class="slds-radio" for="{!answer.Id}">
                <input type="radio" value="{!answer.Is_Correct__c}"  onchange="{!c.markAnswer}"
                       data-id="{!answer.Id}" name="options" id="{!answer.Id}" />                  
                <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">{!answer.Description__c}</span>
              </label>
              </aura:iteration>
            </div>
       </fieldset>
    </aura:if>
```

Please suggest how to bind input variables with sobject fields in lightning framework.

Comment: Some things to check - what does your attribute definition look like? How are you assigning the return value from the Apex controller? Are you sure the return value contains the correct data? Is the binding working one way (ie writing out data)? Does anything happen when you hit the radio button? Oh and have you used the Chrome or Safarai debuggers to examine what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Winter'17 org, then you could use the `<lightning:input type="radio"/>` component which aligns the LDS styled component in Lightning Experience.Here's the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) for it.

But if the org you are working on is Summer'16, then you have to manually set the `Is_Correct__c`.

you need to do something like this:

**Component:**

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.question.Answers__r}" var="answer" indexVar="index">  
    <label class="slds-radio" for="{!answer.Id}">
        <input type="radio" checked="{!answer.Is_Correct__c}" onchange="{!c.markAnswer}"
               data-id="{!answer.Id}" name="options" id="{!answer.Id}" data-ansIndex="{!index"}/>                  
        <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
        <span class="slds-form-element__label">{!answer.Description__c}</span>
    </label>
</aura:iteration>
```

**controller.js**

```
({ 
    markAnswer : function(cmp, event, helper) { 
        var question = cmp.get("v.question");
        var answers = question.Answers__r
        var selectedAnsIdx = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-ansIndex');

        for(var i = 0;i < answers.length;i++){
            if(i != selectedAnsIdx){
                answers[i].Is_Correct__c = false;
            }
        }

        answers[selectedAnsIdx].Is_Correct__c = true;
        cmp.set("v.question",question);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying and for the code. It looks like even after binding is done when tried to render options with radio button selected it is not working. I think I need to go with lightning based components which is going to be future for lightning framework.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar you have to add the `checked` property to the radio button.I have updated the answer.

Comment: Just wanted to note that lightning:input is not a panacea - it requires to enter `label` and does not support certain attributes like `inputmode='numeric'`.